# Storage efficiency of Postgres index column

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

In my PostgreSQL database, I have this table:

```
    Table "public.data"
  Column   |  Type  | Modifiers 
-----------+--------+-----------
  group_id | bigint | 
      item | text   | 
     price | real   | 
Indexes:
    "group_id_index" btree (group_id)
```

`item`'s are organized into groups, and the `group_id` column will have individual values appearing many times in the table. Queries to this table have the form:

```
SELECT item, price FROM data WHERE group_id = 1234;
```

`group_id_index` speeds up these queries (as is its purpose).

My question is, does the presence of the index make Postgres realize it **does not have to store the `group_id` column** behind-the-scenes? If only one copy (for the index) of each value of `group_id` is stored, that would save a lot of space.

This is, if it matters, PostgreSQL version 9.4.1

Comment: 9.4.1? Upgrade NOW. Why on earth would you keep running an old point release like that? In this case there are *known serious bugs* in 9.4.1. Upgrade urgently to the latest in the 9.4.x series. You do not need to dump and reload, just install the new binaries.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but unfortunately it's not in my control. This database lives on a shared virtual cluster that is updated pretty infrequently

Comment: then migrate somewhere else, because that one's going to *destroy your data*.There are *severe* bugs in 9.4.1. Read the release notes. Get regular dumps going. And plan your migration.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, does the presence of the index make Postgres realize it does not have to store the group_id column behind-the-scenes?

No. PostgreSQL uses heaps, not index-organised tables.

Comment: Hi Craig, thanks for your answer, but can you expand on it or provide any references?

Comment: @AntsySysHack The source code is the primary reference here. But it's the absence of references - there's nothing that says it *does* do what you want.